# How to retrieve all table columns, data type, data length, constraint type and referenced column and table

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I'm able to list most of the information needed but can't figure out how to list the referenced tables and columns

the information needed are:

1. Table name
2. Column name
3. Data type
4. Constraint type
5. Reference table
6. Reference column

> ```
>  SELECT
>     at.owner,
>     at.table_name,
>     atc.column_name    AS column_names,
>     atc.data_type      AS data_type,
>     ac.constraint_type
> FROM
>          all_tables at
>     JOIN all_tab_columns   atc ON at.table_name = atc.table_name
>     LEFT JOIN all_cons_columns  acc ON atc.column_name = acc.column_name
>                                       AND acc.table_name = at.table_name
>     LEFT JOIN all_constraints   ac ON ac.constraint_name = acc.constraint_name
> WHERE
>     at.owner NOT IN ( 'SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'DBSNMP', 'DVSYS', 'GSMADMIN_INTERNAL',
>                       'LBACSYS',
>                       'MDSYS',
>                       'OJVMSYS',
>                       'ORDDATA',
>                       'WMSYS',
>                       'XDB',
>                       'CTXSYS',
>                       'APPQOSSYS',
>                       'AUDSYS',
>                       'OUTLN',
>                       'DBSFWUSER',
>                       'ORDSYS',
>                       'OLAPSYS' )
> GROUP BY
>     at.owner,
>     at.table_name,
>     ac.constraint_type,
>     atc.column_name,
>     atc.data_type,
>     ac.r_owner
> ORDER BY
>     at.owner;
> ```

Is there a way I can get all the constraints along with referenced key and table name? I have tried a lot but not able to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need outer self join. Look at the following example:

Master table:

```
SQL> create table master (id_mas number constraint pk_mas primary key);

Table created.
```

Detail table, whose `ID_MAS` column references the master table:

```
SQL> create table detail (id_det number constraint pk_det primary key,
  2                       id_mas number constraint fk_det_mas references master (id_mas));

Table created.
```

Query that returns info you're looking for. Note outer self join with both `USER_CONSTRAINTS` and `USER_CONS_COLUMNS` (lines #8 and 9):

```
SQL> select mt.table_name,
  2         mtc.column_name,
  3         mt.constraint_type,
  4         --
  5         mtr.table_name ref_table_name,
  6         mtrc.column_name ref_column_name
  7  from user_constraints mt join user_cons_columns mtc on mtc.constraint_name = mt.constraint_name
  8  left join user_constraints mtr on mtr.constraint_name = mt.r_constraint_name
  9  left join user_cons_columns mtrc on mtrc.constraint_name = mtr.constraint_name
 10  where mt.table_name in ('MASTER', 'DETAIL')
 11  order by mt.table_name desc, mt.constraint_type;

TABLE_NAME      COLUMN_NAME     CONSTRAINT_TYPE REF_TABLE_NAME  REF_COLUMN_NAME
--------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
MASTER          ID_MAS          P
DETAIL          ID_DET          P
DETAIL          ID_MAS          R               MASTER          ID_MAS

SQL>
```

The 3rd rows reads as: in `detail` table, there's the `id_mas` column which references `master` table's `id_mas` column.